# Java is backward compatible but while trying to upgrade JDK version 1.7 to 1.8 in my android project it's not running

Tags: android, dependencies, java-8

I have created a "Hello World" app which works in JDK 1.8 but when i tried to upgrade my working project I am getting below error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
    ... 12 more
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':Wallet:dexKtakDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 1):

JDK's are (usually) forward compatible.
JRE's are (usually) backward compatible.

Android Environment does not support Java 8 as of now. Supports up to Java 7 (for kitkat).

Java 7 or higher is required if you are targeting Android 5.0 and higher.

Comment: I have minSdkVersion 15, targetSdkVersion 23 so I can use 1.8

Comment: Yes, you can use Java 8

Comment: Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000) is the error I am getting.

Comment: that's because you are using Java 8 I guess, revert back to 7 if necessary!

Answer (score 1):

As everyone explained android still compile on java 7. I faced issue because of the java library included in project was taking sourceCompatibility = 1.8.

I solved this issue by adding

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
```

code in gradle file.

Also in android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

under `defaultConfig` clause

Now my android project runs with JDK 1.8